# 'PDF' Exception with Pillow module and cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf-generation, python-imaging-library, cx-freeze

I'm using Python 3.6 with Pycharm and a virtual environment. I'm trying to make a standalone app with cx_Freeze, but I'm catching an Exception when I try to use my app, just called "PDF". Please note that my script is working fine when I run it with Pycharm.

What my app is supposed to do:

- Take a multipages PDF
- Convert each page into JPG
- Assemble them into a
  panel (for example: if I have 12 pages, it make a panel of 3x4
  images)
- Save the result as a PDF with Pillow

And the issue is located at this very last point. It seems that cx_Freeze doesn't import all the necessary modules from pillow. After a little research, I think I have to add an "options" line in my setup.py, but I'm not sure what to add.

Here is my code from my setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

build_exe_options = {"includes": ["PIL"],
                     "path": sys.path
                     }

setup(name = "Make_multislides" ,
      version = "0.1" ,
      description = "" ,
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [Executable("make_multi_v3.py")]
      )
```

Does anyone know what I can do?
Thank you

UPDATE:
Here is the fonction:

```
def createBigImage(x, y, imgs, width, height, files_in_folder, file_name):
try:
    new_img = Img.new('RGB', (x * width, y * height), color=background_color(imgs[0]))
    i = 0
    for j in range(y):
        for k in range(x):
            if len(files_in_folder) == i:
                pass
            else:
                new_img.paste(im=imgs[i], box=(k * width, j * height))
                i += 1
    new_img.save(os.path.join('Multislides', file_name + '.pdf'), format='pdf')
    print("\t Multislide done")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Here is the trace in the cmd:

```
Création du fichier 245501_12345
         Extraction de la page 245501_12345-page01.pdf
         Conversion de la page JPG
         Extraction de la page 245501_12345-page02.pdf
         Conversion de la page JPG
         Extraction de la page 245501_12345-page03.pdf
         Conversion de la page JPG
         Extraction de la page 245501_12345-page04.pdf
         Conversion de la page JPG
         Extraction de la page 245501_12345-page05.pdf
         Conversion de la page JPG
         Extraction de la page 245501_12345-page06.pdf
         Conversion de la page JPG
         Extraction de la page 245501_12345-page07.pdf
         Conversion de la page JPG
         Extraction de la page 245501_12345-page08.pdf
         Conversion de la page JPG
         Extraction de la page 245501_12345-page09.pdf
         Conversion de la page JPG
         Extraction de la page 245501_12345-page10.pdf
         Conversion de la page JPG
'PDF'
         Suppression des fichiers temporaires
```

Sorry if it's in french, but it's says :"Extracting page #number" and "Converting page JPG".
As I told you, the problem is located where it says 'PUB', it's the name of the error, at this place you should see 'Multislide done' refering to the line in the function `new_img.save(os.path.join('Multislides', file_name + '.pdf'), format='pdf')`

UPDATE 2:
I tried to find the python file from the PIL library that handle PDF files, and there were two of them, one called "*PdfImagePlugin.py*" and the other "*PdfParser.py*". I think the issue comes from the first one missing, but I put them both in the lib\PIL folder and now it seems to work. The thing is that the other files in this folder are .pyc files, I don't know if it mays cause issues on another computer. I asked some friends to test it, and now I'm waiting to see if it works. I'll keep you guys in touch!

Comment: What error are u getting?

Comment: As I wrote it in my post, I get the error "PDF", simple as that, that I catch doing a Try...Except Exception

Comment: What I meant is that the last point of my script (Save the image to a PDF with Pillow) doesn't work and then I have the error "PDF"

Comment: Could you show complete error trace

Comment: Do you have enough informations with the Update?